# c# WinForms Detect real visibility of TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, treenode

I have a WinForms TreeView and a tree, built from custom node objects which inherits TreeNode the problem is that these nodes can be displayed in only one tree at the time.
Now I have multiple controls with a TreeView that should display these nodes. How can I indicate that the treeView is displayed? 
I can catch the VisibleChanged event but I don't know how to detect if the TreeView is really visible (The visible property does not change!).

I know that one solution can be to wrap my data in TreeNode objects and not using inheritance from TreeNode. But I hope there is a faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

How do you decide which treeview gets to display the items?

Generally, I don't think that's a good design at all. Better use an `FeedTreeNode(MyObject o)` and a suitable updater.